# Oracle Apex Cards - One card per row

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex the minimum amount of cards per row is 2, but I want to show one card per row. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks, best regards.

Comment: I've done this by setting it to span whatever number of column regions I give it. You can easily have 1 card per row in the right-hand column, for instance.

Comment: What version of APEX are you using?

Comment: Scott, Can you give sample code?